# How to run test suite as a whole?

Tags: robotframework

This is what I've got in `__init__.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   SeleniumLibrary
Suite Setup  SETUP
Suite Teardown  TEARDOWN

*** Keywords ***
SETUP
    Open Browser    ${URL}  ${BROWSER}

TEARDOWN
    Click Element  id=nuke
    Close Browser

*** Variables ***
${URL}    http://localhost:8000
${BROWSER}    Chrome
```

and there are 2 test files in the same directory. Strangely, I can't seem to find how to run it as a whole so the test files can use libraries and setup and teardown tasks from the init file. Until now I had everything in one file so I could just run `robot filename.robot` but now I'm learning better practices and splitting the test file into test suite. How do I run it ?

Comment: This sort of confusion is exactly why I recommend to never use `__init__.robot` files.

Answer (score 2):

Outside of the test suite directory run `robot directory_name`.